# Does Encog has good perfomance at multisocket motherboards with multiple processors?

Tags: c#, multithreading, neural-network, encog

[`Encog`](http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog) has  multithreading support. But as far as I understand, it's good in paralleling at one processor with for example 8 cores. Will it work faster, if I'll buy [motherboard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00B2W81LK) with 4 sockets, and install there four `Intel Xeon E5-4600`? Does anybody tried something similar? Please answer only if you really know, or really tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this question is highly depends on what version of Encog do you using (`Java` or `.NET` or `C++`), and how your own code is written.

As you can easily see, the `.NET` version of Encog [actively using](https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=IMultiThreadable&type=Code) the it's own [`IMultiThreadable`](https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/blob/87b334dd0f45f4777aa9e02d7af5c5752ddaf3e6/encog-core-cs/Util/Concurrency/IMultiThreadable.cs) interface, and there are a [lot of classes](https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=ThreadCount&type=Code) which are using `Parallel` classes for the learning.

For Java the name of the interface is [`MultiThreadable`](https://github.com/encog/encog-java-core/blob/2b9172854d60684a6e6896253fbab987b65d80ed/src/main/java/org/encog/util/concurrency/MultiThreadable.java). There is no interface for `C++` version, but the code still using the [`threadCount`](https://github.com/encog/encog-c/blob/c6560110e70f8bcd197a88c95a186a0769746654/encog-core/encog.h) parameter in [`object.c`](https://github.com/encog/encog-c/blob/c6560110e70f8bcd197a88c95a186a0769746654/encog-core/object.c) file. As I can see, the [`Javascript version`](https://github.com/encog/encog-javascript/blob/master/encog.js) isn't using any multithreading support in `javascript` (can't say even if it has the multithreading support).

So I definetely can say that, YES, it will work faster with more cores at the machine being available (as it use the core classes which can get the advantages of your hardware), if you are using the right classes, for example (in `C#`):

- [`HessianCR`](https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/blob/87b334dd0f45f4777aa9e02d7af5c5752ddaf3e6/encog-core-cs/MathUtil/Matrices/Hessian/HessianCR.cs)
- [`ConcurrentJob`](https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/blob/87b334dd0f45f4777aa9e02d7af5c5752ddaf3e6/encog-core-cs/Util/Concurrency/Job/ConcurrentJob.cs)
- [`ParallelScore`](https://github.com/encog/encog-dotnet-core/blob/87b334dd0f45f4777aa9e02d7af5c5752ddaf3e6/encog-core-cs/ML/EA/Score/Multi/ParallelScore.cs)
- etc

More about Multhithreading apply on Encog can be found here:
[Applying Multithreading to Resilient Propagation and Backpropagation](http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog/mprop/compare.html)

Comment: I'm particularly interested in C# edition. In other words if Parallel in C# can use 4 processors with 4 cores, then C# version of Encog will work faster

Comment: If CLR produce the IL-code from the Parallel class being able to work with that hardware during JIT-compile, if you want to be exactly right. If you'll precompile your application, it can be a problem with performance.